# how to hook iframe post event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<iframe>` which shows another sites' `<div>` element ([this is the src url](http://qafqazislam.com/az/index.php#namaz_saatlari_content))

In this `<div>` when you select a dropdown this page posts back and then reloads pure site, not with #divname url

Plase look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QsGGg/6/)

How can I save the URL when the city select is changed

**Note that, I have no access to source site (which I must show in iframe)**

Comment: Where do you wan't to save it ? Anyway: You should replace `onchange="load()"` with `onload="load()"` to get your alert.

Comment: with `onload` doesn't works again, please try yourself in jsFiddle

Comment: Is your script running on the same domain as the site accessed in the iframe ? Otherwise it is impossible to get the current url of an iframe (for security reasons).

Comment: No, i have no access :(

Comment: Is there are any way to web scrap this div?